# Draw a bar chart using C# in windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, bar-chart

Can I draw a bar chart using C# ? Do I want to use separate library for that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [MS Charting Controls](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) provided by Microsoft.

You should start accepting more answers as well.

Comment: Can I use Ms Charting controls for windows form application?
If so where can I find good tutorials as I am a beginner in this subject?

Comment: @C. Karunarathne - Yes, you can. They work with winforms, webforms and WPF. There are samples with the download.

Answer (score 2):

You can also check [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page)

Answer (score 2):

Check out [DundasCharts](http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Chart/index.aspx). This library is paid, but it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

As **npinti** suggests, I would also recommend [ZedGraph](http://www1.zedgraph.org/?subid4=1564348329.0119459023&kw=Graphing+Software&KW1=Data%20Visualization%20Software&KW2=Chart%20and%20Graphing%20Software&KW3=Help%20Desk%20Ticket%20System&searchbox=0&domainname=0&backfill=0)

Here you have a lot of examples of barcharts you can draw with ZG:
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Bar_Charts

Here is also a quite useful explanation on various display settings
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=How_is_BarItem_affected_by_AxisType%3F

ZedGraph provides not only the drawing/charting routines, but also basic interactivity (zooming, checking values of the points etc.) and useful operations (saving in various formats, printing, copying to clipboard).

And some simple example:

[image]